# Java write bytes from Bytebuffer to File in byte format

Tags: java, android, arrays, bytebuffer, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm building a custom file creater app with Android. I'm attempting to write the contents of a Bytebuffer, which are String members from a custom class I created, to a file in byte type. However, whenever I do so I get the contents of the file in String format. I've tried several alternatives such as using get method, BufferedOutputStream class, ByteArrayOutputStream class, DataOutputStream, Filechannel class, etc. Here is my code:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(totalSize);

    byteBuffer.put(hm.getDocID().getBytes());
    byteBuffer.put(hm.getFextension().getBytes());
    byteBuffer.put(hm.getMagic().getBytes());
    byteBuffer.put(hm.getFversion().getBytes());
    byteBuffer.put(hm.getFsize().getBytes());

    byteBuffer.flip();

    byte[] bablock = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];

    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(idHeader));

        bos.write(bablock);
        bos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Keep getting the following contents on my idHeader file:

12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abcjpgIDF1.00000166178

Which is all of my Strings concatenated. What I would like to do is write the same contents as bytes to the file, not as a human-readable string. What I am missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of building Strings and getting byte arrays from them and putting those to the `ByteBuffer` and writing that to the file, you need to write the data directly. I would get rid of the `ByteBuffer` and use the various APIs of `DataOutputStream` to write the individual bytes or ints or whatever.

It being entirely unclear whether you want to write `12345678` as 8 bytes or as a 4-byte integer, for example, it is impossible to help you further without clarification.

Comment: Really appreciate the quick response. The idea is that I would like to append a unique file ID (i.e. hm.getDocID().getBytes()) to the created file and be able to retrieve such data after reading the file with a server. Would you suggest to write this id for instance (12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789) as 8 bytes or 4 bytes?

Comment: It won't fit into either 4 or 8 bytes. You need at least 12, 14 if you include the hyphens. Your question is really most unclear. What exactly is wrong with the way you're writing it now?

Comment: Using DataOutputStream directly solved my issue! Apologies for such vague questions on my part. Thanks for the help!